# MVC List Children - Which Controller

Tags: mvc, asp.net

We are currently devloping a ASP MVC Webapplication. In this Webapplication, we have a User that can have 1 or many contracts.

We currently have 2 controller:

- UserController
- ContractController

Now we want to display all Contracts for a User. Which of the above Controllers should contain the Action to List all Contracts for a User?

Further: Where to place the actions if one actions only displays the empty form, and the other action delivers the contracts via Json.

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the controller from the User screen, use the UserController.  If you're calling the controller from the Contracts screen, use the Contracts controller.  And if you're displaying a list of contracts in both places, use both controllers.